# clang error when integrating facebook ios api

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, facebook

So I am trying to integrate the facebook iOS api into my iphone app. I copied the src folder to my project and disabled AR with: '–fno-objc-arc' to all the new files since my project has ARC enabled. The problem is that I am still getting this error and I can't figure out how to solve it. I have been spending the last two days trying to solve this and searched everywhere so any help would be VERY much appreciated.

[image]

The FB SDK files I added to my project:

[image]

[image]

got to say, this API is not so friendly overall...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you actually copied the parameter to disable ARC (–fno-objc-arc) from Xcode, you may notice that you use the en dash (–) instead of the regular - in the beginning, try -fno-objc-arc.

Comment: wow, this is amazing..it actually looks the same in the info.plist. Now I have two other errors, are they related?

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBFrictionlessRequestSettings", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Facebook.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 2):

There is also second way do link facebook API to your App, you can drag and drop src directory from facebook api but you have to uncheck add to target and check "Create groups for any added folders" as in this [image: screenshot]

and you have to go to Projektu -> Targets -> Build Phases and link libfacebook_ios_sdk.a as in screen:
[image: screen2]

now should be all ok, and remember Facebook instance must be in your AppDelegate !